# Doctrine 2 where two associations exists query

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I have two entities related, and I need a query that checks if entityOne have two different relations (extra column as diff field) to entityTwo.

A simple "WHERE entityTwo.diff_field = 1 AND entityTwo.diff_field = 2" don't work.

How can I achive this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('one');
  $query->addSelect('two')->leftJoin('one.two', 'two');
  $query->where('two.id = :a')->setParameter('a',1);
  $query->andWhere('two.id = :b')->setParameter('b',2);
```

EntityOne

```
class EntityOne {
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false);
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntityTwo", mappedBy="one")
     */
    protected $two;
}
```

EntityTwo

```
class EntityTwo {
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false);
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="EntityOne", inversedBy="two", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="one_two_xref")
     */
    protected $one;
}
```

Comment: Show us your database scheme and tell about mysql/mssql/oracle/postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two EXISTS subqueries.

You want (I think) to select entityOnes which have
a linked entityTwo with diffType 1 and also a linked entityTwo with difftype 2.

If you scroll down to 'EXISTS in WHERE clause with correlated Subquery' in this documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

I think what you need is a similar query but with two separate EXISTS subqueries, something like :

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT EntityTwo ... DiffType = 1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT EntityTwo ... DiffType = 2)
```